# WCF undel load won't release memory till the load ends - probably sessions

Tags: wcf, load

I have a component X acting both client and server. Both client and server connections are WCF. The problem is that under high load it seems that WCF won't release sessions or something of a kind. I reached that conclusion following those indications:

1) Memory constantly grows for that component under load.

2) Memory profiler AQTime shows no leaks. Calling Garbage Collector actively (using GC.Collect and GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers) during load releases some memory but it's still growing. But after the load is switched off, all the memory is being released.

3) After I changed communication framework from WCF to ZeroMQ between that component and the one he connects to the memory acts much better - it almost won't grow.

The description of the component :

It connects to component Y using net.tcp binding and listens with net.tcp as well. The bindings definitions are:

```
 <binding
      name="netTcpBinding_Server"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824"
      maxBufferSize="1073741824"
      transferMode="Buffered">
      <security mode="None" />
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="1073741824" maxStringContentLength="1073741824" />
    </binding>

    <binding name="netTcpBinding_Client"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824"
      openTimeout="00.00:00:30"
      closeTimeout="00.00:00:30"
      receiveTimeout="Infinite">
      <security mode="None" />
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="1073741824" maxStringContentLength="1073741824" />
    </binding>
```

Behaviors are:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServerServiceBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions="64" maxConcurrentCalls="128" maxConcurrentInstances="192" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServerEndPointBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600"/>
      <protobuf/>
    </behavior>

    <behavior name="ClinetEndPointBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600"/>
      <protobuf/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="protobuf" type="ProtoBuf.ServiceModel.ProtoBehaviorExtension, protobuf-net, Version=1.0.0.280, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=257b51d87d2e4d67"/>
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
```

If someone wants more details I will be happy to give whatever I can. Could someone tell me please whether it's a familiar behavior and whether I can do something about it?

Thanks in advance!

Maxim

Answer (score 0):

Stuff like this: maxBufferSize="1073741824" will cause WCF to grab that much ram and never let it go until the app is unloaded.

You are telling the framework that you intend to give it 1,073,741,824 bytes of data at moment in time so "be ready" for that reason it will hold that amount of ram space no matter what to save performance hits with things like the GC.

You're basically telling that endpoint "always consume over 1GB of ram".

also how can you have an array or string value the size of your buffer ???

maxArrayLength="1073741824" 
maxStringContentLength="1073741824"

These settings make no sense.